# Force.com IDE in Eclipse Access Denied

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I try to install Force.com plug in based on [instruction](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) , but it fail at step 3..At first I thought it is maybe because of network connection in my company.So I try to paste the url 'http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42' to browser using my own pc and it return

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>46601DF924AEF065</RequestId>
<HostId>
69+wWRDdv+hN1QsUVPTBWc8uNDZNraCh9T935NFmmpyCf754FT9mwU4gkMpIYw71
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Have anyone face the issue before?

Comment: I can confirm I receive the same message when attempting the link in a browser but when using Eclipse IDE (Kepler) I can access the software with that link.  In fact I have just upgraded my Eclipse installation.  What, if any,  is the error you receive in the IDE?  Are you sitting behind a proxy, you may need to amend the proxy settings in Eclipse?

Comment: I paste the URL in my pc at browser which is unlikely look proxy configuration.Do you successfully install the plugin?What is setting that you did?

Comment: My browser does show the same access denied message - the IDE (It's eclipse Kepler on the same computer ) loaded it successfully but I have configured a proxy.  So all I did was open Eclipse, go to Help, Selecting Install new Software, enter the URL in your query to the text box "Work with:" and the options appear...I tick Force.com IDE and install it.  When you enter the URL into the box, make sure there are now apostrophes/quoataion marks.  If it's correct what happens, is there an error? or does it simply stay blank?